Better way to count by gender in sql?
I have the following (simplified) SQL Query:
   select 
       sum(case when gender=1 then 1 else 0 end) as Male, 
       sum(case when gender =2 then 1 else 0 end) as Female from 
       ( select distinct pp.person_id, gender
          from PERSON_VISITS p, PERSON pp
         where p.visit_date between &p_start_date and &p_end_date
         and p.person_id=pp.person_id)

Basically I have the table PERSON_VISITS which consists of a VISIT_DATE Column, a PERSON_ID column and some other columns (which are not needed in this context).
Then I got the PERSON table, which stores the Customer Data like name, gender and so on.
So I want to generate a list of how many of our visitors where male and female.
A Customer can visit us many times , so there can be multiple entries for one person_id in PERSON_VISITS.
The above is a very simplified version of my actual query so I wonder if there is a "better" or simpler way in achieving this ?
Edit:
I tried an alternative version like this :
      select sum(case when gender=1 then 1 else 0 end) as Male, 
       sum(case when gender =2 then 1 else 0 end) as Female from 
       person p where exists 
       (select 1 from person_visits t 
       where t.visit_date between &p_start_date and &p_end_date
       and t.person_id =p.person_id)

But I still think there must be a possibility in making the whole statement a bit shorter or am I wrong?

Well, that's more or less "it", I don't know whether you can make it much shorter (if you're talking about number of characters used :)).
However, what might be more efficient is exists:
SELECT SUM (CASE WHEN p.gender = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Male,
       SUM (CASE WHEN p.gender = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Female
  FROM person p
 WHERE EXISTS
          (SELECT NULL
             FROM person_visits v
            WHERE     v.person_id = p.person_id
                  AND v.visit_date BETWEEN &p_start_date AND &p_end_date)

Make sure that both person_id and visit_date are indexed.

You could count distinct people instead of using a subquery:
select count(distinct case when pp.gender=1 then pp.person_id end) as Male, 
       count(distinct case when pp.gender=2 then pp.person_id end) as Female
from PERSON_VISITS p
join PERSON pp
on pp.person_id=p.person_id
where p.visit_date between &p_start_date and &p_end_date

fiddle
The count function ignores nulls, and the case expression now defaults to null (via the implied else clause; you can explicitly do else null if you prefer) - so person IDs with non-matching genders are not counted.

You haven't shown how p_start_date and p_end_date are defined, but if those are just dates without times specified - e.g. define p_start_date="date '2024-01-01'" and define p_end_date="date '2024-01-31'" - then bear in mind that would end up evaluated as:
where p.visit_date between date '2024-01-01' and date '2024-01-31'

and then after midnight on the last day might be lost, even though the date part matches. If you are defining the range like that then I would prefer to avoid between and instead do:
where p.visit_date between >= &p_start_date
and p.visit_date < &p_end_date + 1

which would evaluate as:
where p.visit_date >= date '2024-01-01'
and p.visit_date < date '2024-01-31' + 1

which would include everything up to (but not including) midnight on 2024-02-01.
Of course, you may be doing define p_end_date="to_date('2024-01-31 23:59:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')" in which case between will work - but it's more typing, and if you were dealing with a timestamp column with fractional seconds that could still cause you problems.
